# Replacement for rectByIntersecting in swift 3

Tags: swift

I wanted to learn more about custom gesture recognizers so I was reading the Ray Wenderlich tutorial, which I planned to modify in order to learn the details and what I can change easily to learn how each piece works, but it was written in a previous version of Swift. Swift updated most of the code and I was able to fix the rest manually save a replacement for rectByIntersecting. The website and code snippet are as follows:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/104744/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-creating-custom-recognizers

let overlapRect = fitBoundingBox.rectByIntersecting(pathBoundingBox)

As shown in the tutorial this is just a check to make sure the circle drawn is an actual circle and not just an arc, or S or 8, etc.

The error is that a value of type CGrect has no member rectByIntersecting, since it was removed when Swift was updated.

I wasn't able to find much as far as a replacement for this, so I was wondering if I'm missing an easy fix or if I should attack if from a completely different angle?

Comment: Did you browse https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect to find a replacement?

Comment: Thank you, I was looking in the wrong place. I used:
let overlapRect = fitBoundingBox.intersection(pathBoundingBox)

Comment: @MartinR nothing found regarding `rectByInsetting` on developer.apple.com